# jquery selector find element from other

Tags: jquery, html

I have the follow html:

```
<div id="x">

   <div id="x1">
   </div> 
   ....
</div>
....
<div id="x2">
   <table id="y">
   </table>
</div>
```

From "x" I need to reach "y", something like $("#x").find("#y")

Suppose that I do not know what has in the "...".

How to do this?

Comment: `id` attributes should be unique within a document, so you can just write `$("#y")`.

Comment: Ids should be unique so finding `y` should always be done with just `$("#y")`.  Can you expand on what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Tell us more about what you *do* know.  Do you know for sure that x and x2 are siblings (i.e. at the same depth)?  Do you know, from x, that y's parent is called x2?

Comment: Why not just $("#y")? Why? because that's what you do, and also you should never have elements with the same ID. If you do need this, use CSS classes, or create your own attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go up one level with `parent()` and use `find()` from there.

```
$('#x').parent().find('#y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('#x').siblings().find('#y')
```

In truth though this makes little sense to do given that both elements in this case have `id` values.  It's much faster to just search for `#y` directly.  If you do actually have multiple `id`s with the same value that's a problem and you should move to an id generation scheme or classes

Comment: You probably want to replace the `next()` function with the `siblings()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is...

```
$('#y', $('#x'))
```

The second parameter is the scope of the selector.